List Directories and SubDirectories - Assign Variable to each
I'm really struggling to find a way to list the directories of a given folder and also the subdirectories without adding in the files, as well as assigning them to a variable.
I've tried using getcwd, global, GLOB_ONLYDIR scandir, but can't get it to work out.
Is there anyway to assign each folder only to a variable?
$currentFolder2 =  getcwd();

foreach (glob($currentFolder2 . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
    $files = glob($dir . '/*');
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($files);
    $link[0] = $files;
    foreach (glob($files . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
        $subfiles = glob($dir . '/*');
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($subfiles);
        $sublink[0] = $files;
    }
}

What I need to produce is folder links:
-Link to Folder1
  -Link to Folder1-SubFolder1
  -Link to Folder1-SubFolder2
-Link to Folder2
  -Link to Folder2-SubFolder1
  -Link to Folder2-SubFolder2
-Link to Folder2
  -Link to Folder2-SubFolder1
  -Link to Folder2-SubFolder2

It's not laying out the way I planned and it's also returning html pages for some reason.
Have I over complicated the way I am going about it or have I gone completely the wrong way.

This question is similar to: How to efficiently use DirectoryIterator?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To append values to an array, do not use the index. $link[] = $files;

$files . '/*' makes no sense. $files is an array, not a string, you can't concatenate it.

What you probably want is foreach ($files as $subdir) { $subfiles = glob("$subdir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR); ... }

The logic:

Scan all files and folders with scandir() that returns an array of everything
Check each object if it is directory with is_dir() function an if so, process it
Scan current directory for step 1 and 2 that will process sub directories

You need 2 calls to scandir(): one for root and one for each parent folder
Sample code:
$content = ''; //For collecting future <li>'s
$folders = array_diff(scandir(ROOT_PATH, 1), array('.', '..', '.ftpquota', '.htaccess', 'index.html', 'index.php', 'error_log'));
if ($folders) {
    foreach ($folders as $folder) {
        if (is_dir(PATH_TO_$folder)) {
            $content .= '<li class="parent">'.$folder.'</li>'; //Add to any html you like
            
            // Now, scan this folder for subfolders:
            $subfolders = array_diff(scandir(ROOT_PATH.'/'.$folder, 1), array('.', '..', '.ftpquota', '.htaccess', 'index.html', 'index.php', 'error_log'));
            if ($subfolders) {
                foreach ($subfolders as $subfolder) {
                    if (is_dir(PATH_TO_$subfolder)) {
                        $content .= '<li class="child">'.$subfolder.'</li>'; //Add to any html you like
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Check it

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
